# Angular mat-tree-node filter inside tree on grandchild level only

Tags: angular, filter, tree, angular6, angular-material2

I have an angular material tree on which it should have filter inside tree- node that is inside the tree (3rd level).When I click on child then filter should appear along with grandchildren. I saw an example below in which filter outside tree and filtering entire node:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yb37gh?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.html

If.we look above example I need filter on under Istanbul and it should provision to filter below child elements. I mean filter on grandchildren level and should able to filter only grandchildren

I.have tried a sample in which when I.filter grandchild it will re-render tree and because filter inside the tree itself, the filter also re-render so the I can.not able to.hold the value on filter.

Has anyone come across adding filter inside tree? Please help

Something like below I am expecting. Search on all nodes on that level only.

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?